# Correlation between gravity and time dilation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, time-dilation

If gravity field increases logarithmically, should time dilation increase proportionately? say gravity increases to $g=10$, $g=100$, $g=1000$, or even $g=10,000$; what should the time difference be at a given at those distances.

Singularities have infinite gravity and as you approach, the gravity field increases.

How strong would the gravity field be to create a  time dilation of say a $10:1$, or $100:1$ second difference?

10 or 100 seconds on earth = 1 second in the gravity field?

What would the escape velocity have to be at those spots.

What would a hyperbolic orbit to drop into and out of the gravity field to end up with the time difference look like with all the parameters?

What would be the relativistic speeds be?

Answer (score 2):

Can not give you a simple relation but here is what I could get.

$$ T_1 = T {\sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{rc^2}}} \tag{1}$$
$$g = {{\frac{GM}{r^2}}} \tag{2}$$

Substituting $g$ in $(1)$, you get

$$ T_1 = T {\sqrt{1 - \frac{2gr}{c^2}}} \tag{3}$$

$$ T_1' = T {\sqrt{1 - \frac{2g'r}{c^2}}} \tag{4}$$

You can see how $\frac{T_1'}{T_1}$ depends on $g$ and $g'$ from $(3)$ and $(4)$.

Note that $r$ appears in the equation which is the distance from the center of mass which is providing the gravitation.